# Are there any advantages from an SEO perspective to remove the "/category/" base from the permalink?

Tags: seo, url, wordpress

On an WordPress site, there are ways to remove the `/category/` base from permalinks. Is there an advantage or a disadvantage for SEO to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO is a good stuff but don't forget your users. That's why from my experience with WordPress, I always remove the `/category/` in the URL because:

- URLs are shorter (better for SEO)
- URLs are easy to remember (better for users)
- URLs doesn't refer to English language (if your site is for example in French, German...)